# Error while importing tensorflow in Linux terminal

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, import

When i tried to import tensorflow in linux python terminal it is showing the following error
        "Illegal instruction (core dumped)"
but when i try to run my python script in sublime text editor using tensorflow libraries it is working fine.i don't know how to solve in former case please help me in this regard
                           Thank you

Comment: I'd suggest you add the actual commands you ran and the actual output (error) from the terminal. Very difficult to say anything based solely on a description. Also, linux distro and version number, Tensorflow version number, how you installed it (pip v building from sources), which Python (2 v 3) you use.

Comment: hari@hari-VPCEA23EN:~$ python
---------------------------Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
------result------Illegal instruction (core dumped)-------------------------------------linux   version 16.04 and python version is 3.6.4..

Comment: And which Tensorflow version are we talking about and how have you installed it? Also, you can edit your own original question with the new information, that makes it much more legible than comments. An idea: are you sure you compiled / installed Tensorflow for Python 3?